# How to delete core the data which is present in parent and child entities

Tags: swift

How to delete the child entity data (automatically) when the parent entity data is getting deleted using iOS swift core data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the relationship as [Cascade](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW1) in the model.

Comment: i think this is must be a comment instead of answer. also your provided Link is mac development.

Comment: ok i also saw that link... where we need to set cascade in the entity i mean parent or child entity?

Comment: Neither. It is in the Relationships. Look for drop down called Delete Rule in the inspector.

Comment: ok you mean the relationship means line between the two entity right ?

Comment: i tried that too i got deleted in parent table but in child table data is still there ? i don't know where i went wrong ?

Comment: Try deleting the app to force refresh the model and the database.

Comment: you meen the reset simulator ? .... i tried that too

Comment: Just delete the app from the device/simulator and rebuild/reinstall. If that does not help, I would suggest creating a new simple project and testing this in isolation. There isn't much more that I can offer here. Sorry!

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question.